# Why Binance klines last close value with interval is different from others?

Tags: python, binance

I am getting the candle stick values from binance api and print them like following.

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    service = BinanceSpotService()
    klines = service.get_klines(symbol='BTCUSDT', interval=Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_15MINUTE)
    print(klines[["date", "close"]].tail(2))
```

each loop prints the last two datas like this:

```
 date                    close
498 2022-11-13 07:45:00  16774.99
499 2022-11-13 08:00:00  16769.12


                   date     close
498 2022-11-13 07:45:00  16774.99
499 2022-11-13 08:00:00  16769.10


                   date     close
498 2022-11-13 07:45:00  16774.99
499 2022-11-13 08:00:00  16772.34


                   date     close
498 2022-11-13 07:45:00  16774.99
499 2022-11-13 08:00:00  16770.48
```

the last item date does not change but close values are different. Why is this so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Anwer: The most recent kline is still constantly changing.

In your example, you do not pass any `endTime`.
This gets then passed over to the Binance API. When there is no defined `endTime`, the API will return the most recent klines.

```
If startTime and endTime are not sent, the most recent klines are returned.
```

[source](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#kline-candlestick-data)

Applied to your example:
You are getting the klines data multiple times in a loop. The most recent kline (`klines[-1]`) is the one, which is constantly changing, because the time window is still open and therefore changes with every trade made.